# Eclipse: Next word shortcut case insensitive

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a lot CTRL + arrows to jump to the next word in Eclipse. But it's case sensitive and I don't want it to stop in camelCase words. Is there a way to make a case insensitive word navigation shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered here: [Configure Eclipse word-boundaries so 'Next-Word-Key' skips whole identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399102/configure-eclipse-word-boundaries-so-next-word-key-skips-whole-identifier)

Unselect the option: Preferences / Java / Editor / Smart caret positioning in Java names.

Note that you will have to do this for each type of language you are using. So, for javascript files, unselect the option: Preferences / Javascript / Editor / Smart caret positioning in JavaScript names.