# How can I configure the Eclipse editor (or PyDev) to treat a dot as a word boundary on Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, pydev

I use Eclipse with PyDev on Mac OS 10.7.  For some reason, my editor doesn't recognize '.' as a word boundary, so `ctrl+right` (i.e. the "Next Word" command) skips over an entire series of identifiers.  For example, hitting ctrl+right skips across this entire series of identifiers, as shown by the carets:

```
someObject.someProperty.someMethod()
^                                 ^
```

This is SO FRUSTRATING.  It makes it annoying to use shift+ctrl+right to select only a single identifier.  How can I fix this behavior?

Note: The preference setting referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399102/configure-eclipse-word-boundaries-so-next-word-key-skips-whole-identifier) does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The issue turned out to be caused by a Mac OS **System Preferences** setting.

**10.9 (Mavericks) and later:**

The *Word Break* option has been removed in Mavericks. Instead:

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences AppleTextBreakLocale en_US_POSIX
```

Sources:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104143/how-do-i-change-which-characters-os-x-considers-a-word-for-%E2%8C%A5-arrow-key-skippi
- https://twitter.com/jaydisc/status/393157866812502016
- http://lri.me/osx.txt

**10.8 and earlier:**

Many thanks to @Fabio Zadrozny for describing the fix in [this old PyDev issue thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/bugs/1119/?limit=10&page=1#80de):

> Go to System Preferences > Language & Text > Text, and set the ‘Word
>   Break’ dropdown to ‘English, United States (Computer)’.

... then restart Eclipse and you're good to go!